# how to make a v2 credential provider initialize its credentials without `ICredentialProviderUser` object?

Tags: c++, credential-providers, windows-credential-provider

i built a V2 credential provider sample and registe it to windows10, the provider can be load and displayed in unlock screen after i click "Sign-in options", but the provider can not be displayed in power-on/switch-user logon screen. i put some log in the code like this

```
HRESULT CSampleProvider::_EnumerateCredentials()
{
    DebugTrace(__FILEW__, __LINE__, _T("enter _EnumerateCredentials"));

    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;
    if (_pCredProviderUserArray != nullptr)
    {
        DWORD dwUserCount;
        _pCredProviderUserArray->GetCount(&dwUserCount);

        **DebugTrace(__FILEW__, __LINE__, _T("    dwUserCount = %d"), dwUserCount);**

        if (dwUserCount > 0)
        {
            ICredentialProviderUser *pCredUser;
            hr = _pCredProviderUserArray->GetAt(0, &pCredUser);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                _pCredential = new(std::nothrow) CSampleCredential();
                if (_pCredential != nullptr)
                {
                    hr = _pCredential->Initialize(_cpus, s_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors, s_rgFieldStatePairs, pCredUser);
                    if (FAILED(hr))
                    {
                        _pCredential->Release();
                        _pCredential = nullptr;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
                }
                pCredUser->Release();
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```

turns out dwUserCount is 0 in power-on/switch-user logon screen, so that the provider will not initialize any credential.
My question is, how to make the provider initialize its credentials without `ICredentialProviderUser` object?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The exact answer - noway.**

New `Windows Logon` scenario assumes that there are some users that can login into computer and have an option to choose which provider use for login.

Each `User's tile` will have a set of icons from Credential Providers registered on computer.

Your provider must accept a list of users that can be logged on the computer and make a decision to **display or not** it's icon next to user's tile.

The only possible way in this situation is to implement a default tile behaviour, as described in v1 credential provider guide.

Comment: thank you very much for answer my question. i download a sample code from here [link](https://github.com/multiOTP/multiOTPCredentialProvider) ,there is a processing for dwUserCount == 0 in its `_EnumerateCredentials` function, looks like it set a default user tile as you mentioned, i'll have a learn on it.